# How to remove activity from activity backstack?

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have two activities Activity A and Activity B. When I click  button in Activity A, The Activity B starts. Now When I press back button from Activity B the Activity A get restarted. But I want to come out of the app when the back button in Activity B is pressed. I tried using this but not getting success

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finish `ActivityA` once you're starting `ActivityB`:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call finish() after starting new Activity - this will close the calling Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));

//calling finish() closes current Activity
finish();
```

Read more about Activity life cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just call finish() after startActivity(intent).

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is not suitable for your situation.In your code,ActivityA will re-builded again.There has two instances of ActivityA in the TaskStack.Delete the addFlag.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```